# Is there a way to select top 100 or 1000 bag of words based on Tfidfvectorizer output in scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scikits

I am trying to find top 100/1000 words based on [tfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) output of Python's scikit-learn library. Is there a way to do it using a function from the scikit libraries?

Thanks for help

Comment: top 100/1000 words based on tfidf values given by tfidf vectorizer. I tried to sum up values for every column , but indexing is not allowed in sparse representation

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by top 100/1000 words? The most frequent words in a dataset? You can use the [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) class of the Python standard library to do that. No need for scikit-learn.

Comment: top 100/1000 words based on tfidf values given by tfidf vectorizer. I tried to sum up values for every column , but  indexing is not allowed in sparse representation .

Comment: @user595169 Do you mean `X.sum(0)`?